# WinForms App Doesn't Run Outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, C#, Windows Forms application on a new laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate.

From within VS, if I Build and run my app, it opens fine (no errors or warnings).  If go into the debug folder and double click the exe file, the app doesn't open.  It appears in task manager, but I can't kill it.  I get no error messages.  Because it's running, I can no longer Build or run the project from VS as the file is in use.

I tried Building to Release and got the same problem.

The only way to get rid from the task manager is to restart the laptop.

This wasn't a problem on my old PC - which also had Win7 Ultimate and VS2013.

Do you know why my exe isn't running and why I can't kill it in Task Manager?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have administrator permission on your new laptop?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "log" - sorry.  Yes, I have a admin rights - it's my own private laptop (not a company one).  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I have VS Express 2015 for Windows Desktop. Recently build app worked only from Visual Studio, old builds work fine. After some research I found that the promblem was my Avast Antivirus 2015, which prevented the new apps from running.
So I suggest, if you have Antivirus running, pause it for a while and see what happens. If indeed that is was the cause for your problems, the configure Antivirus so  that it will not check your app when loading. 
In Avast: Settings->Active protection->File system protection
(Not sure if that is excatly so, because I have Avast in other language than english)
Hope that works!

Comment: This solved the problem - many thanks.  I am using VS2013 Express and Avast free edition.  In Avast, Settings, Active Protection, if I turn off File System Shield, my exe opens.  If I turn it back on, the exe goes back to not opening.  There's a lot of settings in Customise in File System Shield, but I've turned it on and in Customise, Scan when executing, I've unticked Scan programs when executing.  This solves the problem too.  There may be a way though to have this ticked and add exceptions for my VS directory, which may be better.....but that's great - many thanks.

Comment: NOTE: Windows defender is a problem too.I closed it and my apps ran succesfully.If anyone has the same problem i may be WindowsDefender.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Avast 2015 (licensed) that locks File Explorer up if I double click my c# apps in the bin\debug or release folders.

As others have suggested, rather than disabling Avast "Scan programs while executing" you can add your app path into the scan exclusion list via:

1. Left click the Avast Icon
2. Click Settings
3. Click Active Protection
4. Click Customize link for "File System Shield"
5. Click Exclusions and add your build folder.  e.g. \bin

Also,
If Windows Explorer has locked up because of this issue, rather than rebooting you can open Task Manager, end-task "Windows Explorer" (your start bar will vanish) then click File->Run new task and type in Explorer, then hit enter to get everything back.

Cheers